# React Native: borderBottomWidth not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Fonts from '../Fonts';
import Screen from '../Screen';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(12, 22, 32, 0.88)",
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: "#47315a",
  },
  content: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: Screen.height() - 450.0,
    width: Screen.width() - 50.0,
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: "#47315a",
  },
  header: {
    alignItems: "center",
    paddingBottom: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    color: "#0B1219",
    fontFamily: Fonts.Knockout31JuniorMiddleWeight,
    fontSize: 26.0,
    borderBottomWidth: 5,
    borderBottomColor: "#47315a",
    fontWeight: '300',
  },
});

const PlaceOrder = () => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <View style={[styles.content]}>
        <Text style={styles.header}>
          HEADER TEXT
        </Text>
        <Text>dzfaksjads fahksl</Text>
        <Text>
          We'll start preparing your blah when you blah blah
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PlaceOrder;
```

However, the bottomBorderWidth and bottomBorderColor aren't working.

[image]

When I change it to use `borderWidth` it works, but I only want the bottom to have a border:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Indigo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-apple-pay": "0.0.0",
    "react-native-button": "^1.7.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^1.11.0-beta",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-paged-scroll-view": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.0.1",
    "react-redux": "latest",
    "redux": "^3.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "latest",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of react-native are you using? What's the platform? This works without any problems on 0.34.

Comment: sorry, i updated the question with my package.json file

Comment: In older versions of react you only could specify `borderWidth` and `borderColor`; properties like `borderBottomWidth` etc were only added later on.

Answer (score 14):

Just wrap the `Text` node with `View` and add border bottom to the `View`.

```
contentWrapper: {
  borderBottomWidth: 5,
  borderBottomColor: "#47315a"
}
```